# how to use in-repo-addons in the ember-engines?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-addon, ember-engines

I have created and ember in-repo-addon. Let's say `say-hello`. After that I created ember-eninge. Let's say `users-engine`.

In may main application I can directly use the addon as

```
//application.hbs
{{say-hello}}
```

How to use it in the users-engine ?

```
//lib/users-engines/templates/index.hbs
{{say-hello}} //It is not working also not throwing any error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer but not sure whether it is correct way or not.

In the `users-engine/package.json` add relative path to addons

```
{
  "name": "users-engine",
  "keywords": [
    "ember-addon",
    "ember-engine"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "*"
  },
  "ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "../say-hello"
    ]
  }
}
```

and now you can use in-repo-addon in ember-engine directly.

```
//lib/users-engines/templates/index.hbs
{{say-hello}} //It is working now.
```

Comment: I'm with the exact same problem, but for me your solution did not work. :(

Comment: Adding path must work. but just check the path of your addon. or post your code here

Comment: I did exactly what you did, but in my case did not work. I had to do an instance initializer like Cryrivers are suggesting in his post: https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/issues/236